# What is the correct usage of rstrip(';') to remove everything on the right of ';' from a string?

Tags: python, string

I have a string, which I cannot share, but basically has a series of ";" separating different elements. Just to have an idea is like the below.

`T = 'dfcuhlefcv;fcuygewcrg'`

When running the below command to strip everything on the right hand side of the character ";"
`T.rstrip(';')`

returns the same value as the original string T.

I also tried re-assigning to a different variable but nothing. As amtter of fact, it only works if give a whle series of characcters form the right, in the specific order, which is not what I want, and it is not what I find on the web.

I tried

`T = 'dfcuhlefcv;fcuygewcrg'`
`T.rstrip(';')`

I expected the notebook to return
`'dfcuhlefcv'`

Comment: Do you want an answer with Python?

Comment: `rstrip` isn't even the correct tool for the job in the first place, let alone `rstrip(';')`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my way in using the split command. It gets trickier when dealing with a DataFrame so this is what I came up with, which solves my problem in a parametric way

```
Data = ['wuytdfed;dhvcdwhvc','edxwecrdwqr;tvhtrgythghy','cewdre;qedwr'] #Simulated sample data of a dataframe column
Produc_List = pd.DataFrame(data=Data,columns=['Product_Names']) #Simulated sample dataframe
N_Col = max(list(map(lambda s: s.count(';'), Product_List.Product_Numbers))) #Max number of times the separator is used in the column where to split the strings
Col_Names = [f'PN_{i}' for i in range(N_Col+1)] # List comprehension to automatically generate list of column names where to insert the data after splitting it at the chosen separator, i.e. ";"
Product_List[Col_Names] = 
Product_List.Product_Numbers.str.split(';',expand=True) # Adding the split elements in each of the new columns of the dataframe
```

I hope this helps someone else in my same situation.

Answer (score 0):

With Python you can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> T.split(';')[0]
'dfcuhlefcv'
```

I suppose in R:

```
>>> strsplit(T, ';')[[1]][1]
"dfcuhlefcv"
```